# Do I need to connect to my mongodb database within my jest test file or can I call functions from other classes that connect to the database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, jestjs

I'm trying to test some of my database functions with jest. I currently have a javascript file with various functions. These functions connect to the database at the beginning of each one, do some retrieval from the DB, then return an array. I'm trying to just call those functions from my jest file and test the return value of those functions, but I'm getting this error:

> MongoParseError: URI malformed, cannot be parsed

My functions works fine outside of being called from my test file, so I can only assume there is some issue about NOT connecting to the database from the test file.

Example function connection to the database

```js
export async function getPrograms(programId): Promise<any> {
  console.log("calling get programs");
  console.log(programId);
  const db = await commonDb.getInstance();
  console.log("Database: ", db);
  programId = programId ? programId : "";
  const regex = new RegExp(`.*${programId}.*`, "i");
  const programs = await db
    .collection(COLLECTIONS.COMMON.PROGRAMS)
    .find({ _id: regex })
    .toArray();
  if (programs.length > 0) {
    console.log(programs);
    return programs;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Example test I'm trying to run that throws the error

```js
import {
  getPrograms
} from "../../../src/classes/programs";

test("calling getPrograms with no programId gives all programs", async() => {
  const programs = await getPrograms("someId");
  expect(programs).toBe(["someProgram"]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So my issue was that I wasn't setting up my environment variables. I added these two the top of my code.

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
```